# Bing ads API Exception

Tags: php, bing-api, bing-ads-api

We are using Bing Ads API for advertising our products through the campaign ads. We have installed the Bing Ads API and while trying to get the authentication we are facing the exception as follows,

```
SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/
    CampaignManagement/v9/CampaignManagementService.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity 
    "https://api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/CampaignManagement/v9/CampaignManagementService.svc?wsdl"

)
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 0):

Version 9 and 10 are no longer supported [Bing Ads web services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/web-service-addresses), so please check the [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/migrate-bing-ads-api-version-11) for details about version 11. If you have any follow up questions please let us know. You can also reach out via the [Bing Ads Developer Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=BingAds).